# How to use inspect element for selection tab in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a code than logins to a webpage and tries to download a file. but after login and before downloading it requires to select a particular field from drop down and then select a particular tab to download the file, can anyone pls assist what could be done here ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "products.markit.com/home/login.jsp"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username"))).send_keys("Admin")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("admin123")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "button"))).click()
```

Inspect element for first selection (Pricing Data - Loan)

[image]

Inspect element for Past Loan Market

[image]

Inspect element for Download tab

[image]

Comment: The flow is , once we have logged to the website, next step is to choose pricing data-loan from drop down menu then click on download tab from the top right then choose "past loan market" then click on download to get the file

Comment: There are plenty of other Q&As on this site regarding using Selenium to click certain places and select options from menus. After reading those pages, what question (singular) do you still have? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service.

Comment: i think her question is how to select download tab from the page

Comment: I couldn't open a link you shared

Comment: URL is not working.

Comment: here is the updated link : https://products.markit.com/home/login.jsp

Comment: Hi @Prophet, can you please help ?

Comment: I'm here. I'm also working now :) but will try to help

Comment: The code you shared doesn't perform login. what should I insert in username filed? "Admin" not works, it should be an email address

Comment: HI Prophet, can i pls share the login details with you on chat ?